# How to set a progress bar for an encryption algorithm?

Tags: java, android

I am using the algorithm at http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/DesFile.html, i would like to know how to implement a spinner algorithm for this, i have got
codes like

```
public class ProgressBarExample extends Activity {

ProgressThread progThread;
ProgressDialog progDialog;
Button button1, button2;
int typeBar;                        // Determines type progress bar: 0 = spinner, 1 = horizontal
int delay = 40;                   // Milliseconds of delay in the update loop
int maxBarValue = 200;      // Maximum value of horizontal progress bar

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Process button to start spinner progress dialog with anonymous inner class
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            typeBar = 0;
            showDialog(typeBar);
        }
    }); 

    // Process button to start horizontal progress bar dialog with anonymous inner class
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            typeBar = 1;
            showDialog(typeBar);
        }
    }); 
}

// Method to create a progress bar dialog of either spinner or horizontal type
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch(id) {
    case 0:                      // Spinner
        progDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progThread = new ProgressThread(handler);
        progThread.start();
        return progDialog;
    case 1:                      // Horizontal
        progDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progDialog.setMax(maxBarValue);
        progDialog.setMessage("Dollars in checking account:");
        progThread = new ProgressThread(handler);
        progThread.start();
        return progDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

// Handler on the main (UI) thread that will receive messages from the 
// second thread and update the progress.

final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // Get the current value of the variable total from the message data
        // and update the progress bar.
        int total = msg.getData().getInt("total");
        progDialog.setProgress(total);
        if (total <= 0){
            dismissDialog(typeBar);
            progThread.setState(ProgressThread.DONE);
        }
    }
};

// Inner class that performs progress calculations on a second thread.  Implement
// the thread by subclassing Thread and overriding its run() method.  Also provide
// a setState(state) method to stop the thread gracefully.

private class ProgressThread extends Thread {   

    // Class constants defining state of the thread
    final static int DONE = 0;
    final static int RUNNING = 1;

    Handler mHandler;
    int mState;
    int total;

    // Constructor with an argument that specifies Handler on main thread
    // to which messages will be sent by this thread.

    ProgressThread(Handler h) {
        mHandler = h;
    }

    // Override the run() method that will be invoked automatically when 
    // the Thread starts.  Do the work required to update the progress bar on this
    // thread but send a message to the Handler on the main UI thread to actually
    // change the visual representation of the progress. In this example we count
    // the index total down to zero, so the horizontal progress bar will start full and
    // count down.

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mState = RUNNING;   
        total = maxBarValue;
        while (mState == RUNNING) {
            // The method Thread.sleep throws an InterruptedException if Thread.interrupt() 
            // were to be issued while thread is sleeping; the exception must be caught.
            try {
                // Control speed of update (but precision of delay not guaranteed)
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "Thread was Interrupted");
            }

            // Send message (with current value of  total as data) to Handler on UI thread
            // so that it can update the progress bar.

            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("total", total);
            msg.setData(b);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

            total--;      // Count down
        }
    }

    // Set current state of thread (use state=ProgressThread.DONE to stop thread)
    public void setState(int state) {
        mState = state;
    }
}
```

}

how do i implement a spinner using the above class for the DES algorithm??

Comment: what you want actually cant Understand ? spinner ? check what is spinner in android

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: i understand the spinner thingy,i want to know how to get the progress update from the DES encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Wow thanks, but could you tell me how to implement it?I still dont understand how to use it with the DES encryption algorithm.It is a simple example but how do i get the progress update of an encryption process?